# How to solve SassError: Invalid parent selector "*"?

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

I have an Angular 9 app and when I use this snippet SCSS it returns this error:

```
SassError: Invalid parent selector "*"
   ╷
52 │         &#{$value} {
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

This is the snippet:

```
$values: (
  "":"",
  one: one,
  two: two,
);

@mixin gen() {
  @each $value, $key in $values {
    @media (min-width: 300px) {
      &#{$value} {
        @content
      }
    }
  }
}

@mixin display {
  display: block;
}

.display > * {
  @include gen() {
    @include display();
  }
}
```

I want in output classes for each value like: `display > *`, `display-one > *`, `display-two > *`and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** You want to select `*` after the `value >`, means you should add it in the mixin

**2.** You want select `-#{$value}` and not just `&#{$value}`. So *A-* you have to add the `-`, and *B-* for `$value=""` the `-` is not exist. so probably you should give it special attention.

Shortly, change the scss to

```css
$values: (
        one: one,
        two: two,
);

@mixin gen() {
  @media (min-width: 300px) {
    > * {
      @content
    }
  }
  @each $value, $key in $values {
    @media (min-width: 300px) {
      &-#{$value} > * {
        @content
      }
    }
  }
}

@mixin display {
  display: block;
}

.display {
  @include gen() {
    @include display();
  }
}
```

Output:

```css
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .display > * {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .display-one > * {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .display-two > * {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What [@Yosef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8508777/yosef-tukachinsky) describes is correct – however, there are a few things to consider

When using @each loops on maps the order is `$key, $value`.

To minimize the CSS output move the @each loop **inside** the media query – like:

```
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  //  move loop here
  @each $key, $value in $values {
    ...
  }
}


// CSS output without redundant media queries
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .display > * {
    display: block;
  }
  .display-one > * {
    display: block;
  }
  .display-two > * {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Last but not least **consider not doing this at all** – use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) instead – this way you can handle everything in one selector :-)

```
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  [class|=display] > * { display: block; }
}

// This will match 
.display > *, .display-one > *, .display-two > *, .display-xxx > * etc.
```